# How can i pass/use private variables froma class in Form1 with a public function?

Tags: c#

I don't want to make a new instance of Form1 in the class, and i dont want to use `static`.

I have these two variables which are private in the top of the class:

```
private List<float> Point_X = new List<float>();
private List<float> Point_Y = new List<float>();
```

Now in the Form1 I created a new instance for the new class: `WireObject1`.

I need that in Form1 so that I will be able to type:

```
WireObject1.Point_X
// Or 
WireObject1.anyFunctionherethatwillcontainthePOINT_X
```

Same for the Point_Y.

In the class they are private, but using a public function in the class I'll be able to use them in the Form1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand what you need.
Anyway, you could try to use a public property:

```
public List<float> PointX { get { return Point_X; } }
public List<float> PointY { get { return Point_Y; } }
```

Comment: In the end i created a property  public List<float> _point_X
        {
            get { return Point_X; }
        } for both Lists. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<float> GetXValues()
{
    return Point_X.AsReadOnly();
}
```

If I understand, you want to give read-only access to `Point_X` outside of the class. This method will allow you to do that. Or you could use a read-only property:

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<float> XValues
{
    get
    {
        return Point_X.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

The key thing is the `AsReadOnly` method call to prevent changes to the collection outside of the class. If you return the `List<T>` directly, it can be changed by the caller.

Comment: but who says that OP's doesn't want to change collection?

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to this:

1. Make the variables public properties - though there are issues around the use of lists so having a `ReadOnlyCollection` wrapper is the way to solve this.
2. Create a public method that performs the required manipulations on the lists.

For example to add a point to the list you'd have:

```
public void AddValueToX(float value)
{
    PointX.Add(value);
}
```

If you wanted to test whether a value was in the list (which is fraught with danger as you are dealing with single precision values):

```
public bool InListX(float value)
{
    // A test on value vs the data in Point_X allowing for floating point inaccuracies
}
```

Comment: ... although this would presumably involve testing a floating point number for equality, which doesn't come without its own pitfalls...

Comment: @DavidM - indeed - which is why I didn't specify the test itself :)

Comment: I guessed that might be the case - no harm in pointing out for the sake of posterity though I thought...

Comment: @DavidM I've updated the answer to a) make this clearer and b) provide a better example

Answer (score 0):

The canonical solution is

```
private List<float> mPoint_X = new List<float>();
private List<float> mPoint_Y = new List<float>();

public List<float> Point_X { get { return mPoint_X; } }
public List<float> Point_Y { get { return mPoint_Y; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can not* use private fields of a class inside another (cause Form is just another class).
What you *can* do, if limiting the accessibility is important to you, is using `internal` keyword, instead of `private`. But it will work **only** if both classes are in the same assembly.

```
internal List<float> Point_X = new List<float>();
internal List<float> Point_Y = new List<float>();
```

To be clear it's always a good to have some property or method that "wraps" access to the private fields, but as much as I understood it's not something you want to avoid, for some reason.